# Declaring QStringlist variable globally, Getting location path using QFileDialog and printing it to a lineEdit and using it in QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt4.8

I am using Qt and I need some help

1. How to declare `QStringList` variable globally in Qt so that I can access it in any function?
2. How to print all the stuff in `QStringList`(it contains the file path which it took from `QFileDialog`) to a `lineEdit`?

I tried:

```
ui->lineEdit->setText(filename);
```

But it gave me error error:`QString` to non-scalar type `QStringList` requested.
Please give me some examples.

Comment: A `QLineEdit` requires a single string, you're passing an arbitrary amount of strings - how do you want it formatted?

Comment: Yes, my QStringList contains only 1 string :D but I wish to use QStringList only instead of QString.

Comment: Weird logic. I'd go with a QString in your case but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to declare QStringList variable globally in Qt so that I can access it in any function

Well this isn't a `Qt` question, but a general C++ one (global variables are frowned upon these days, a more acceptable equivalent is the singleton, search SO for lots of examples).  Nonetheless, one way of doing this would be create the `QStringList` as a static member of the class that instantiates the `QFileDialog`, the same class will be the one that retrieved it from the dialog anyway and by storing (and returning) it statically you effectively make it global:

```
class A
{
public:
    void openFileDialog() { // Open the dialog, and store the results in list_. }
    static const QStringList& getFileList() { return list_; }
private:
    static list_;
}

// Just call by:
QStringList list = A::getFileList();
```

> How to print all the stuff in QStringList(it contains the file path which it took from QFileDialog)
>
> Yes, my QStringList contains only 1 string

Well, if your `QStringList` only contains one string just use:

```
ui->lineEdit->setText(list_[0]);
```

Remember a `QStringList` is derived from `QVector< QString >`, so you can access the individual `QString`s just like any element.

Just to expand your first question, there an infinite number of ways a list of strings can be combined into a single one.  But a very common (and easy) method with `QStringList` is to use `join()`:

```
QStringList list; list << "This" << "is" << "a" << "list.";
list.join( " " ); // "This is a list. "
```

I really recommend using the [docs](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/), Qt's are brilliant .

Comment: Thank you for prompt answer here is my modified code
QString filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open Backup Element","/home","Images(*.img)");

ui->lineEdit->setText(filename[0]);

This is giving me error "No matching function for call to 'QLineEdit::setText(QCharRef)'

Comment: Because you have changed `filename` to be `QString`, not a `QStringList` like it was originally, it is now indexing each letter of the `QString`.  You can now just pass `filename` without the index operator.  As Dirk suggested I really recommend reading a beginner C++ book, the problems you are having have nothing to do `Qt`.

Comment: Oops sorry but I pasted wrong code and wrong error message too :D
QStringList filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,"Open Backup Element","/home","Images(*.img)");
    ui->lineEdit->setText(filename[0]);

And error is 'QString' to non-scalar type 'QStringList requested as in OP
Well regarding C++ I am not an expert but have basic knowledge which I wish to refine with Qt and then move to other stuff
thank you for your help

Comment: `QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(..)` returns a `QString`, whilst `QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(..)` return a `QStringList`.

Comment: Ah....didn't knew that, thanks, well I am stuck only on 1 issue now, I want to access a QStringList variable in a function which is defined and declared in other function. I know its a simple C++ question but I am really in urgent need of that. Thank you

Comment: You need to make it a member variable of the class that contains the method (I'm assuming it's a method, and not a 'free-standing' function), and provide a getter method to return it.  You post questions rather than ask them in comments of unrelated questions, otherwise people who are suffering the same problem won't be able to search for them.  And if my answer answered your original question, mark it as accepted :)

Comment: "_Remember a `QStringList` is derived from `QVector< QString >`_" Last time I checked the docs, `QStringList` was a typedef of `QList<QString>` not QVector.

Answer (score 1):

You should reconsider using a global variable; it's usually better to pass a reference to functions that need access to it but if you must, this is how you do it. Put a definition as normal in one of your source files

```
QStringList foo;
```

and put a extern declaration in a header file that you include in all the files that you want to use it in like this

```
extern QStringList foo;
```

Wanting to pass a list of strings to a line edit also seems misguided; it would be better to just pass in a string like it expects, but if you absolutely must pass in a list you would have to subclass QLineEdit and give it a method that takes a string list and gets a string from that list which it passes to QLineEdit::setText.

Comment: Oh how to pass reference to other function to access its variable? it seems good idea instead of global declaration

Comment: You just declare it like any other function parameter but put a & after the type. For example, void foo(QStringList& bar). If you didn't already know this you should probably pick up a book on C++ before you proceed much farther.

Comment: I tried this but I get a error again while compiling with error: error: prototype for 'void MainWindow::on_pushButton_12_clicked(QString&)' does not match any in class 'MainWindow'

Comment: You're either missing the declaration of the function in the class body or the declaration doesn't match your definition.

Comment: No, when I remove 'QString& myvariable' from the parameter, it compiles correctly, also when I try int& myvariable' it compiles correctly but not with QString